# Agent-based Immutable Map

Tags: functional-programming, f#, hash-map, immutability

I am in the process of removing the last few pieces of mutable state from an F#-based distributed system.  Some of the remaining mutable state is a `ConcurrentDictionary` used in some Akka.net actors to store messages, look them later, update their statuses, etc.  We had some problems with locking on the `ConcurrentDictionary` instances, so we believe it worth replacing them with an immutable implementaiton.  In order to replace the concurrent dictionaries, I have created a wrapper around the F# Immutable `Map<'key, 'value>` type using a `MailboxProcessor` to process dictionary operations one-at-a-time.  My implementation is as follows, let me know if you see any problems with using this to replace `ConcurrentDictionary`.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type private MapMessage<'key,'value when 'key: comparison> =
| Add of 'key*'value*AsyncReplyChannel<Map<'key, 'value>>
| Contains of 'key*AsyncReplyChannel<bool>
| Count of AsyncReplyChannel<int>
| Get of 'key*AsyncReplyChannel<'value option>
| GetAll of AsyncReplyChannel<Map<'key, 'value>>
| Remove of 'key*AsyncReplyChannel<Map<'key, 'value>>
| Update of 'key*'value*AsyncReplyChannel<Map<'key, 'value>>
| Keys of AsyncReplyChannel<'key seq>
| Values of AsyncReplyChannel<'value seq>

type MapAgent<'key,'value when 'key: comparison> () =
    let agent = MailboxProcessor<MapMessage<'key,'value>>.Start
                 <| fun inbox ->
                    let rec loop (state: Map<'key,'value>) =
                        async {
                            let! message = inbox.Receive()
                            match message with
                            | Add (key, value, channel) -> 
                                let newState = state |> Map.add key value
                                channel.Reply(newState)
                                return! loop newState
                            | Contains (key, channel) ->
                                channel.Reply(state |> Map.containsKey key)
                                return! loop state
                            | Count channel ->
                                channel.Reply(state |> Map.count)
                                return! loop state
                            | Get (key, channel) -> 
                                channel.Reply(state |> Map.tryFind key)
                                return! loop state
                            | GetAll channel -> 
                                channel.Reply(state)
                                return! loop state
                            | Remove (key, channel) ->
                                let newState = state |> Map.remove key
                                channel.Reply(newState)
                                return! loop newState
                            | Update (key, value, channel) ->
                                let newState = 
                                    state 
                                    |> Map.remove key
                                    |> Map.add key value
                                channel.Reply(newState)
                                return! loop newState     
                            | Keys channel ->
                                channel.Reply(state |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map fst)
                                return! loop state
                            | Values channel ->
                                channel.Reply(state |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map snd)
                                return! loop state
                        }
                    loop Map.empty

    let postAndReply = agent.PostAndReply

    let postAndAsyncReply = agent.PostAndAsyncReply

    let postKeyAndReply key messageBuilder = 
        agent.PostAndReply <| fun reply -> messageBuilder (key, reply)

    let postKeyAndAsyncReply key messageBuilder =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply <| fun reply -> messageBuilder (key, reply)

    let postKeyValueAndReply key value messageBuilder =
        agent.PostAndReply <| fun reply -> messageBuilder (key, value, reply)

    let postKeyValueAndAsyncReply key value messageBuilder =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply <| fun reply -> messageBuilder (key, value, reply)

    let add key value =
        Add |> postKeyValueAndReply key value

    let asyncAdd key value =
        Add |> postKeyValueAndAsyncReply key value

    let contains key =
        Contains |> postKeyAndReply key

    let asyncContains key =
        Contains |> postKeyAndAsyncReply key

    let count () =
        Count |> postAndReply

    let asyncCount () =
        Count |> postAndAsyncReply

    let get key =
        Get |> postKeyAndReply key

    let asyncGet key =
        Get |> postKeyAndAsyncReply key

    let getAll () =
        GetAll |> postAndReply

    let asyncGetAll () =
        GetAll |> postAndAsyncReply

    let remove key =
        Remove |> postKeyAndReply key

    let asyncRemove key =
        Remove |> postKeyAndAsyncReply key

    let update key value =
        Update |> postKeyValueAndReply key value

    let asyncUpdate key value =
        Update |> postKeyValueAndAsyncReply key value

    let keys () = 
        Keys |> postAndReply

    let asyncKeys () =
        Keys |> postAndAsyncReply

    let values () =
        Values |> postAndReply

    let asyncValues () =
        Values |> postAndAsyncReply

    let getEnumerable () =
        seq {
            for (key, value) in getAll() |> Map.toSeq -> KeyValuePair<'key, 'value>(key, value)
        }

    let getEnumerator () =
        getEnumerable().GetEnumerator()

    let compare (kvps: KeyValuePair<'key, 'value> seq) =
        let comparer = LanguagePrimitives.FastGenericComparer<'key>
        Seq.compareWith 
            (fun (kvp1 : KeyValuePair<'key, 'value>) (kvp2 : KeyValuePair<'key, 'value>) -> 
                let c = comparer.Compare(kvp1.Key, kvp2.Key) in 
                if c <> 0 then c else Unchecked.compare kvp1.Value kvp2.Value)
            (getEnumerable()) 

    let containsKeyValue key value =
        contains key && 
            (match get key with
             | Some value -> value |> Unchecked.equals value
             | None -> false)

    member __.Add key value = add key value
    member __.AsyncAdd key value = add key value
    member __.ContainsKey key = contains key
    member __.AsyncContainsKey key = asyncContains key
    member __.Get key = get key
    member __.AsyncGet key = asyncGet key
    member __.GetAll () = getAll ()
    member __.AsyncGetAll () = asyncGetAll ()
    member __.Remove key = remove key
    member __.AsyncRemove key = asyncRemove key
    member __.Update key value = update key value
    member __.AsyncUpdate key value = asyncUpdate key value
    member __.Values () = values ()
    member __.AsyncValues () = asyncValues ()
    member __.AsEnumerable () = getEnumerable ()

    override __.Equals that = 
        match that with
        | :? seq<KeyValuePair<'key, 'value>> as map -> (compare (getAll()) map) = 0
        | _ -> false

    override __.GetHashCode () =
        getAll() |> box |> fun o -> o.GetHashCode()

    interface IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<'key, 'value>> with
        member __.GetEnumerator () = getEnumerator ()
    interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
        member __.GetEnumerator () = getEnumerator () :> System.Collections.IEnumerator
    interface IDictionary<'key, 'value> with
        member __.Add (key, value) = add key value |> ignore
        member __.Add (kvp) = add kvp.Key kvp.Value |> ignore
        member __.Clear () = keys() |> Seq.iter (remove >> ignore)
        member __.Contains kvp = containsKeyValue kvp.Key kvp.Value            
        member __.ContainsKey (key) = contains key    
        member __.CopyTo (array, index) = 
            getAll() 
            |> Map.toSeq 
            |> Seq.iteri (fun i (key, value) -> array.[index + i] <- KeyValuePair(key, value))
        member __.Remove (key: 'key) = 
            if contains key
            then (remove key |> ignore; true)
            else false
        member __.Remove (kvp: KeyValuePair<'key, 'value>) =
            if containsKeyValue kvp.Key kvp.Value
            then (remove kvp.Key |> ignore; true)
            else false
        member __.TryGetValue (key, result) = 
            if contains key 
            then match get key with
                 | Some value -> result <- value;true
                 | None -> false
            else false
        member __.Count
            with get () = count ()
        member __.IsReadOnly
            with get () = false
        member __.Item
            with get key = 
                match get key with
                | Some value -> value
                | None -> raise <| System.IndexOutOfRangeException(sprintf "The key %A was not found in the dictionary" key)
            and set key value = update key value |> ignore
        member __.Keys 
            with get () = [| for key in keys () -> key |] :> ICollection<'key>
        member __.Values
            with get () = [| for value in values () -> value |] :> ICollection<'value>
    interface System.IComparable with 
        member __.CompareTo (obj: obj) = 
            match obj with 
            | :? MapAgent<'key, 'value> as mapAgent ->
                compare (getEnumerable()) (mapAgent.AsEnumerable())
            | :? Map<'key, 'value> as map ->
                compare (getEnumerable()) (map |> Map.toSeq |> Seq.map (fun (key, value) -> KeyValuePair(key, value)))
            | _ -> 
                invalidArg "obj" "not comparable"
```