# Lock-free Immutable ConcurrentQueue

Tags: functional-programming, f#, queue, lock-free, immutability

Similar to the code review I posted last week for an [agent-based immutable replacement for `ConcurrentDictionary`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193677/agent-based-immutable-map), I have also created an agent-based immutable replacement for `ConcurrentQueue`.  This uses a `MailboxProcessor` and an immutable queue based on Okasaki's implementation in Purely Functional Data Structures with a few extra operations.  I am particularly interested in understanding if there's any way I can combine the `QueueAgent` and the `InternalQueueAgent` into one type (without the mutual-recursion), and if there's any way to do the asynchronous `Peek` and `Dequeue` operations without the internal `ImmutableQueue`s for the `PeekListeners` and `DequeueListeners`.  The idea behind those operations is to support a "yield until a message is available" behavior similar to an asynchronous `Peek` or `Receive` operation on MSMQ or RabbitMQ.  I also welcome any general feedback on the implementation.

My code for the immutable queue is as follows:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

/// An F# Immutable Queue, based on Okasaki's implementation in Purely-Functional Data Structures
type ImmutableQueue<'message> private (front: 'message list, rear: 'message list) = 
    let enqueue message =        
        match front, message::rear with
        | [], newRear -> ImmutableQueue(newRear |> List.rev, [])
        | _, newRear -> ImmutableQueue(front, newRear)

    let enqueueAll messages = 
        let orderedMessages = messages |> List.rev
        match front, orderedMessages@rear with
        | [], newRear -> ImmutableQueue(newRear |> List.rev, [])
        | _, newRear -> ImmutableQueue(front, newRear)

    let dequeue () = 
        match front with
        | message::tail -> 
            message, (match tail with
                      | [] -> ImmutableQueue(rear |> List.rev, [])
                      | _ -> ImmutableQueue(tail, rear))
        | _ -> failwith "Cannot dequeue from empty queue!"        

    let dequeueAll () =
        (front @ (rear |> List.rev), ImmutableQueue<'message>([], []) )

    let tryDequeue () =  
        match front with
        | message::tail -> 
            (message, (match tail with
                       | [] -> ImmutableQueue(rear |> List.rev, [])
                       | _ -> ImmutableQueue(tail, rear)))
            |> Some
        | _ -> None

    let tryPeek () =
        match front with
        | message::tail -> Some message
        | _ -> None

    let reverse () = 
        match front with
        | [] -> ImmutableQueue(rear |> List.rev, [])
        | _ -> ImmutableQueue(front, rear)

    let getEnumerator () = 
        (seq {
            yield! front
            yield! rear |> List.rev
        }).GetEnumerator()  

    static member Empty = ImmutableQueue<'message>([], []) 
    static member From messages = ImmutableQueue<'message>(messages, [])

    member __.IsEmpty = front.IsEmpty && rear.IsEmpty
    member __.Length = front.Length + rear.Length
    member __.HasMessages = front.IsEmpty |> not
    member __.Enqueue message = enqueue message        
    member __.EnqueueAll messages = enqueueAll messages
    member __.Dequeue () = dequeue ()
    member __.DequeueAll () = dequeueAll ()
    member __.TryDequeue () = tryDequeue()
    member __.TryPeek () = tryPeek()
    member __.Reverse () = reverse()
    member __.GetEnumerator () = getEnumerator()

    interface IEnumerable<'message> with
        member this.GetEnumerator () = this.GetEnumerator()  

    interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
        member this.GetEnumerator () = this.GetEnumerator() :> System.Collections.IEnumerator

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module Queue =
    /// Create an empty queue of the given message type
    let empty<'message> = ImmutableQueue<'message>.Empty

    /// Enqueue a message in the given queue
    let inline enqueue message (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.Enqueue message 

    /// Enqueue all of the provided messages in the given queue        
    let inline enqueueAll messages (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.EnqueueAll messages

    /// Check if the given queue is empty
    let inline isEmpty (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.IsEmpty

    /// Compute the length (number of messages) of the given queue
    let inline length (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.Length

    /// Check if the given queue contains any messages
    let inline hasMessages (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.HasMessages

    /// Create a queue from an F# list
    let inline ofList messages = messages |> ImmutableQueue.From

    /// Create a queue fron an F# sequence
    let inline ofSeq messages = messages |> Seq.toList |> ofList

    /// Dequeue the message at the front of the given queue
    let inline dequeue (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.Dequeue()

    /// Dequeue all the messages from the given queue
    let inline dequeueAll (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.DequeueAll()

    /// Try to dequeue the message at the front of the given queue
    let inline tryDequeue (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.TryDequeue()

    /// Try to peek the message at the front of the given queue
    let inline tryPeek (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.TryPeek()

    /// Reverse the order of all messages in the given queue
    let inline rev (queue: ImmutableQueue<'message>) = queue.Reverse()
```

And here's my implementation of `QueueAgent`:

```
open System.Collections.Concurrent
open System.Collections.Generic

type private QueueMessage<'a> =
| Enqueue of 'a
| EnqueueAll of 'a list
| TryDequeue of AsyncReplyChannel<'a option>
| TryPeek of AsyncReplyChannel<'a option>
| Dequeue of AsyncReplyChannel<'a>
| DequeueAll of AsyncReplyChannel<'a seq>
| Peek of AsyncReplyChannel<'a>
| Count of AsyncReplyChannel<int>
| GetAll of AsyncReplyChannel<'a seq>

type private InternalQueueMessage<'a> =
| AddDequeueListener of AsyncReplyChannel<'a>
| AddPeekListener of AsyncReplyChannel<'a>
| ItemEnqueued of QueueAgent<'a>

and private Listeners<'a> =
    {
        PeekListeners: ImmutableQueue<AsyncReplyChannel<'a>>
        DequeueListeners: ImmutableQueue<AsyncReplyChannel<'a>>
    }
    static member Empty() = {PeekListeners = ImmutableQueue<AsyncReplyChannel<'a>>.Empty; DequeueListeners = ImmutableQueue<AsyncReplyChannel<'a>>.Empty}

and QueueAgent<'a> () as this =
    let internalQueue = InternalQueueAgent<'a>()
    let agent = 
        MailboxProcessor<QueueMessage<'a>>.Start 
        <| fun inbox ->
            let rec loop state =
                async {
                    let! message = inbox.Receive()
                    match message with
                    | Enqueue item -> 
                        let newState = state |> Queue.enqueue item
                        internalQueue.Post <| ItemEnqueued this
                        return! loop newState
                    | EnqueueAll items ->
                        let newState = state |> Queue.enqueueAll items
                        items |> List.iter (fun item -> internalQueue.Post <| ItemEnqueued this)
                        return! loop newState
                    | TryDequeue channel ->
                        match state |> Queue.tryDequeue with
                        | Some (item, newState) ->
                            channel.Reply <| Some item
                            return! loop newState
                        | None -> 
                            channel.Reply None
                            return! loop state
                    | TryPeek channel ->
                        channel.Reply (state |> Queue.tryPeek)
                        return! loop state
                    | Dequeue channel ->
                        match state |> Queue.tryDequeue with
                        | Some (item, newState) ->
                            channel.Reply item
                            return! loop newState
                        | None -> 
                            internalQueue.Post <| AddDequeueListener channel
                            return! loop state                
                    | DequeueAll channel ->
                        let (items, newState) = state |> Queue.dequeueAll
                        channel.Reply items
                        return! loop newState
                    | Peek channel ->
                        match state |> Queue.tryPeek with
                        | Some item -> 
                            channel.Reply item
                            return! loop state
                        | None ->
                            internalQueue.Post <| AddPeekListener channel
                            return! loop state
                    | Count channel ->
                        channel.Reply (state |> Queue.length)
                        return! loop state
                    | GetAll channel ->
                        channel.Reply state
                        return! loop state

                }
            loop ImmutableQueue<'a>.Empty

    let enqueue item =
        agent.Post <| Enqueue item

    let enqueueAll items =
        agent.Post <| EnqueueAll items

    let tryDequeue () =
        agent.PostAndReply TryDequeue

    let asyncTryDequeue () =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply TryDequeue

    let tryPeek () =
        agent.PostAndReply TryPeek

    let asyncTryPeek () =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply TryPeek

    let dequeue () =
        agent.PostAndReply Dequeue

    let asyncDequeue () =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply Dequeue

    let dequeueAll () =
        agent.PostAndReply DequeueAll

    let asyncDequeueAll () =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply DequeueAll

    let peek () =
        agent.PostAndReply Peek

    let asyncPeek () =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply Peek

    let count () =
        agent.PostAndReply Count

    let asyncCount () =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply Count

    let getAll () = 
        agent.PostAndReply GetAll

    let asyncGetAll () =
        agent.PostAndAsyncReply GetAll

    member __.Enqueue item = enqueue item
    member __.EnqueueAll items = enqueueAll items
    member __.TryDequeue () = tryDequeue ()
    member __.AsyncTryDequeue () = asyncTryDequeue ()
    member __.TryPeek () = tryPeek ()
    member __.AsyncTryPeek () = asyncTryPeek ()
    member __.Dequeue () = dequeue ()
    member __.AsyncDequeue () = asyncDequeue ()
    member __.DequeueAll () = dequeueAll ()
    member __.AsyncDequeueAll () = asyncDequeueAll ()
    member __.Peek () = peek ()
    member __.AsyncPeek () = asyncPeek ()
    member __.Count = count()
    member __.AsyncCount () = asyncCount ()
    member __.GetAll () = getAll ()
    member __.AsyncGetAll () = asyncGetAll ()

    interface IEnumerable<'a> with
        member __.GetEnumerator () = (getAll () :> IEnumerable<'a>).GetEnumerator()
    interface System.Collections.IEnumerable with
        member __.GetEnumerator () = (getAll () :> System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()
    interface IProducerConsumerCollection<'a> with
        member __.CopyTo (array: 'a array, index) = getAll () |> Seq.iteri (fun i item -> array.[index + i] <- item)
        member __.CopyTo (array: System.Array, index) = getAll () |> Seq.iteri (fun i item -> array.SetValue(item, index + i))
        member __.TryAdd item = enqueue item;true
        member __.TryTake item =
            match tryDequeue () with
            | Some element -> item <- element;true
            | None -> false
        member __.ToArray () = getAll () |> Seq.toArray
        member __.Count = count ()
        member __.SyncRoot = this |> box
        member __.IsSynchronized = true


and private InternalQueueAgent<'a> () =
    let agent = 
        MailboxProcessor<InternalQueueMessage<'a>>.Start
        <| fun inbox ->
            let rec loop (state: Listeners<'a>) =
                async {
                    let! message = inbox.Receive()
                    match message with
                    | AddDequeueListener channel ->
                        return! loop {state with DequeueListeners = state.DequeueListeners |> Queue.enqueue channel}
                    | AddPeekListener channel ->
                        return! loop {state with PeekListeners = state.PeekListeners |> Queue.enqueue channel}
                    | ItemEnqueued queue ->
                        let! newState =
                            async {
                                match state.PeekListeners |> Queue.tryDequeue with
                                | None -> return state
                                | Some (channel, newQueue) -> 
                                    let! item = queue.AsyncTryPeek()
                                    match item with
                                    | Some a -> channel.Reply a
                                    | None -> ()
                                    return {state with PeekListeners = newQueue}
                            }

                        match newState.DequeueListeners |> Queue.tryDequeue with
                        | Some (channel, newQueue) ->
                            let! item = queue.AsyncTryDequeue()
                            match item with
                            | Some a -> 
                                channel.Reply a
                                return! loop {newState with DequeueListeners = newQueue}
                            | None ->
                                return! loop state
                        | None -> return! loop state

                }
            loop <| Listeners<'a>.Empty()

    member __.Post message = agent.Post message
```

And finally, here are my unit tests for `QueueAgent`:

```
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

[<AutoOpen>]
module Common =
    let inline equal expected actual = Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual)
    let inline notEqual expected actual = Assert.AreNotEqual(expected, actual)
    let inline isTrue value = Assert.IsTrue(value)
    let inline isFalse value = Assert.IsFalse(value)

[<TestClass>]
type QueueAgentTests () = 
    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``Enqueueing should add a message to the queue`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            queue.Enqueue "test"
            queue.Enqueue "test2"
            queue.Enqueue "test3"
            let! count = queue.AsyncCount()
            count |> equal 3
        }

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``Dequeueing should wait for message to be enqueued, then remove the message from the queue`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            let dequeueResult = queue.AsyncDequeue()
            queue.Enqueue "test"
            let! message = dequeueResult
            message |> equal "test"
            let! count = queue.AsyncCount()
            count |> equal 0
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``Peeking should return the first message in the queue without removing it`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            queue.Enqueue "test"
            queue.Enqueue "test2"
            let! peekedMessage = queue.AsyncPeek()
            peekedMessage |> equal "test"
            let! count = queue.AsyncCount()
            count |> equal 2
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``TryDequeue should return None if there are no messages in the queue`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            let! dequeueResult = queue.AsyncTryDequeue()
            dequeueResult |> equal None
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``TryDequeue should return Some if there are messages in the queue, and remove one message from the queue`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            queue.Enqueue "test"
            queue.Enqueue "test2"
            queue.Enqueue "test3"
            let! dequeueResult = queue.AsyncTryDequeue()
            dequeueResult |> equal <| Some "test"
            let! count = queue.AsyncCount()
            count |> equal 2
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``TryPeek should return None if there are no messages in the queue`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            let! peekResult = queue.AsyncTryPeek()
            peekResult |> equal None
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``TryPeek should return Some if there are messages in the queue, and not modify the queue`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            queue.Enqueue "test"
            queue.Enqueue "test2"
            queue.Enqueue "test3"
            let! peekResult = queue.AsyncTryPeek()
            peekResult |> equal <| Some "test"
            let! count = queue.AsyncCount()
            count |> equal 3
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``EnqueueAll should enqueue all elements of a list in the queue`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            let list = [1..10] |> List.map (fun i -> sprintf "Test %d" i)
            queue.EnqueueAll list
            let! count = queue.AsyncCount()
            count |> equal 10
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``DequeueAll should remove all elements from the queue`` () =
        async {
            let queue = QueueAgent<string>()
            let list = [1..10] |> List.map (fun i -> sprintf "Test %d" i)
            queue.EnqueueAll list
            let! elements = queue.AsyncDequeueAll()
            elements |> Seq.length |> equal 10
            list |> List.forall (fun item -> elements |> Seq.contains item) |> isTrue
            let! count = queue.AsyncCount()
            count |> equal 0
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously

    [<TestMethod>]
    member __.``QueueAgent should be thread-safe`` () =
        let queue = QueueAgent<string>()

        [1..10]
        |> List.map (fun i ->
            async {
                queue.Enqueue <| sprintf "Test %d" i
            })
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.Ignore
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

        queue.Count |> equal 10

        [1..5]
        |> List.map (fun _ -> queue.AsyncDequeue())
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.Ignore
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

        queue.Count |> equal 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a thorough review, but two things jump out at me as problematic with `ImmutableQueue`:

1. Your `Reverse` method looks wrong: it doesn't do anything if `front` isn't empty, and doesn't reverse if it isn't. I would have expected:

   ```
   let reverse () = 
       ImmutableQueue(rear, front)
   ```

   There are no tests for this method.
2. Some of the methods of `ImmutableQueue` seem to assume that the queue is empty if `front` is empty, while others do not. Without looking too carefully, I think `front` can never be empty if the whole thing isn't, but this isn't documented, and it's all rather confusing.

   `Enqueue`, for example, will happily handle `front = []`, while `tryPeek` returns `None` if `front = []`, and `tryDequeue` is careful to make sure it doesn't produce an `ImmutableQueue` where `front = []`.